# Using MapBox topojson editor/viewer?

Tags: mapbox, topojson, viewer

I'm converting a map from geojson to topojson, and I'd like to validate that the conversion is ok.

Unfortunately QGIS doesn't seem to support topojson yet.

I've found this excellent MapBox application http://geojson.io/, that worked really well, but now is giving me a [strange error](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson.io/issues/255).

So I'd like to know what editors/viewers are there available with topo

Answer (score 1):

This error should be fixed; I've reopened the issue and would love if you could give more specifics that would help me debug it.